# How to provide routes for Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My controller:

```
 exports.read = function(req, res) {
  Settings.find({},function(err,result) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(result);
    }
  });
};
```

My routes:

```
app.route('/api/settings').get(settings.read);
```

When I do testing with Postman it says error '404 Not found' but when I give it as

```
app.route('/api/settings').post(settings.read);
```

i.e changed from get to post it is working. Can anyone please suggest help?

Answer (score 0):

In current version `'app.router' is deprecated!`
You can use below code in app.js file

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/api/settings', index.read);
```

and can put your read function code in index.js file under routes dir. like this

```
module.exports = {
  read: function( req, res){
    res.send({});
    res.end();
  }
}
```

then you can get the response on get call as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure the `method` option from `Postman` is `GET` NOT `POST`

[image]